# Does GraphVIz for Mac has sfdp laying?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, graphviz

I installed GraphViz 2.36 from MacPorts. I have to process hundreds of nodes and don't need hierarchy, just a readable graph. But GUI does not allow to choose laying. I tried to run this:

```
sfdp -Goverlap=prism -Tpng test.gv > test.png
```

But I get:

```
Warning: Overlap value "prism" unsupported - ignored
Error: remove_overlap: Graphviz not built with triangulation library
```

and a lot of exceptions of `invalid context 0x0`. What can be done here?..

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. Firstly, I updated to 2.38 from MacPorts. Secondly, I found a simple way to make a beautiful graph without additional console attributes:

```
digraph MyGraph {
    graph [layout="sfdp", overlap="prism"];
    ...
}
```